# How to set value in context in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-context

I have used firebase auth in ReactJS, so after login I am fetching schoolid of logged in user from *userTbl* and trying to set that value using useState, but **my problem** is when I am logging, it works , but when I use page refresh the page, value of state is gets cleared.

Pls help me with this.

What I tried.

```
    const [schoolid, setSchoolid] = useState();
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
    
    const mProps = {
        user,
        login,
        schoolid
      };
    
      async function login(email, password) {
        return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      }
    
    
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (currentuser) => {
          setUser(currentuser)
          const docRef = doc(db, "userTbl", currentuser.uid);
          const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
          setSchoolid(docSnap.data().schoolid);
        })
    
        return unsubscribe;
      }, []);
```